# SO-239 (UHF) vs N connector power handling on 160m

Tags: hf, rf-power, coaxial-cable, connectors, pl259-so239-connector

I am curious how much CW power an N connector or SO-239 connector will handle on such a low frequency like 160m band. I know on VHF they will probably handle about 800W before getting too warm.

I have made a high powered transmitter for this band, and I've always used cables with either N or SO-239 in the past. I know something like DIN is recommended for over 1kW, but at these frequencies, I would think the others could handle it. I know the voltage handling of the N connector is 1500 volts peak which is plenty for several kilowatts, but will it get too warm?

https://www.amphenolrf.com/connectors/n-type.html

I am partial to the SO-239 because the center conductor is so much larger.

Does anyone have personal experience using either of these connectors over 1kW? BTW my coax is fine as it's LMR400.

Comment: Not to worry. :-) They'll both more than handle a steady carrier at the legal limit. I use RG-6 and F connectors,  and there was no temperature rise even with my 2000 watt scale pegged into a dummy load.

Comment: I see. LOL thanks ;) ...Oh I thought you were joking about the F connector... That's for TV coax, really?

Comment: *Really*. Note that this is RG-6 (F-6) and not RG-59. It has an almost identical power handling curve as RG-213.

Comment: You might find an answer in [in these earlier discussions](https://ham.stackexchange.com/search?q=Connector+power+bnc+n) here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PL-259/SO-239 vs N Type vs BNC which is best connector to use when?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/13061/pl-259-so-239-vs-n-type-vs-bnc-which-is-best-connector-to-use-when)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The average power rating is determined by overheating of the centre
>   contact and is a function of frequency, as heating depends on the
>   resistive insertion loss. Typical makers curves for a new clean
>   connector with a perfect load such as page 275 of [2] for example
>   imply ~5000 watts at 20 MHz and ~500watts at 2 GHz, i.e. a square root
>   frequency derating law as might be expected from skin depth decreasing
>   with frequency.

(From http://www.terminalblock-elinker.com/news/detail.php/id-345.html)

Since he sites 5kW at 20 MHz, and power handling decreasing with increasing frequency, I think it's safe to say that 2kW at 1.8MHz is no problem.
(Edit: Corrected the power rating at 20MHz)

Comment: I can testify to that. Years ago, I witnessed 10 kW sustained at approximately 160m.